# NetCore 2.1 TestServer Return 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, xunit

I am trying to write an integration test for my API and i am trying to use TestServer on .netCore and using xunit.

But I always get 500 error from the request. I also tried to request to an online link for test (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users) but even this way i am getting 500.

By the way When i run my api and check the methot that i am trying to test is getting 200 and working great.

This is the all message that i get.

---

**Test Name**: RepoCore.TEST.IntegrationTests.IntegrationTest.QueryFromEntitiyTestAsync

**Test FullName**:  RepoCore.TEST.IntegrationTests.IntegrationTest.QueryFromEntitiyTestAsync

**Test Source**: C:\Users\Sercan\source\repos\RepoCore.API\RepoCore.TEST\IntegrationTests\IntegrationTest.cs : line 0

**Test Outcome**:   Failed
**Test Duration**:  0:00:04,645

**Result StackTrace**:
at RepoCore.TEST.IntegrationTests.IntegrationTest.QueryFromEntitiyTestAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

**Result Message**:Assert.Equal() Failure

**Expected**: OK

**Actual**: InternalServerError

---

```
 public class IntegrationTest : IDisposable
 {

    private DataContext _context;
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

        public IntegrationTest()
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Path.GetFullPath(@"../../../../../../")).Build();

            var server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>().UseConfiguration(configuration));

            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection().AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().BuildServiceProvider();


            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext>();
            builder.UseSqlServer("Server=xyz;Database=xyz; User ID=xyz;Password=1; Trusted_Connection=True;").UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
            _context = new DataContext(builder.Options, _logContext);
            _context.Database.Migrate();


            _client = server.CreateClient();
        }




        [Fact]
        public async Task QueryFromEntitiyTestAsync()
        {
            API.Models.Repos newrepo = new API.Models.Repos { RepoName = "TestName2", RepoAdress = "Some Street", IsActive = 1 };

            _context.Repos.Add(newrepo);
            _context.SaveChanges();


            var response = await _client.GetAsync("/api/Repo/GetRepoById?RepoId=" + newrepo.RepoID);

           //var response = await _client.GetAsync("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");


            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);

        }
 }
```

Comment: You can set a breakpoint within your API code and if you debug your test, it will hit that API breakpoint.

Comment: 500 is basically saying something bad happened `inside` the API code - not very helpful for a client but you might have logs you can inspect? - or even better the source code...

Comment: @jonsca Api is working correctly there is not problem there

Comment: @JohnB but also i m getting same 500 when i try external link too. That link is givin correct result and working too

Comment: @SercanSelçuk It's throwing an exception *somewhere* in there when you are running the integration tests.  It could be how you have your tests set up or any number of things.

Comment: In my case, I had a global exception filter which was hiding the exception (an unregistered service). I just removed it temporarily.